# Передать переменную из класса

Tags: java

Друзья, кодеры!
Необходимо передать переменную из класса.

```
public static final String field_96138_a = "!" + randomes.lalka + "!";
public static class randomes {
public static void randoms(String[] args) 
{
String[] currentRoom;
 String [][] rooms = {{"Start", "Treasure Room1"}, {"Goblin Home1", "Spider Nest1"}};

 Random rand = new Random();

 currentRoom = rooms [rand.nextInt(rooms.length)];

textes = (Arrays.toString(currentRoom));

}
public static final String lalka = textes;
                       }
```

Нужно передать переменную "textes" в переменную "lalka";

Comment: переменная lalka имеет модификатор final, она не может быть изменена.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, про то, что метод у вас final, вам написали, ну а присваивания в объявлении метода по типу `lalka = textes` не может быть в принципе.

Создаете метод

```
public static void MyMethod (String myVar)

{

}
```

Вызываете метод с передачей ему параметра, например, переменной:

```
String MyNewVar;

MyMethod(MyNewVar);
```

Как-то так.

А эта конструкция

```
public static final String lalka = textes;
```

должна выглядеть как-то так:

```
lalka = textes;
```

И почему-то вы сперва объявляете переменную, где используете random.lalka, а только потом объявляете lalka. Вам не кажется это нелогичным?